# How to remove this Shimano cassette (actually: freewheel)?

Tags: shimano, cassette, freewheel, tools

A neighbour approached me to help him with removing the cassette from the wheel in the picture below. I am familiar with the modern Shimano lockring but would appreciate tips how to remove this one.

[image: Shimano MF-TZ21 Freewheel]

Comment: Would this useful?　http://escapetrip.jp/roadbike-wheels-exchange/2830

Comment: @TakahiroWaki - Those directions are for a cassette. This is a freewheel. All the cogs are on one unit that threads onto the hub. See the first link in my answer on how these two things are different. Its actually simpler than the procedure outlined there.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Thats a Shimano freewheel, not a cassette. You need a freewheel remover like Park Tool FR-1 to remove it. Note that this is not the same tool as the cassette tool (e.g. Park Tool FR-5 for Shimano-type cassettes).

See [this link](http://www.parktool.com/blog/repair-help/cassette-and-freewheel-removal-and-installation#article-section-6) on how to remove it with the freewheel remover (Recommended method), or [this link](http://www.parktool.com/blog/repair-help/freewheel-destructive-removal) on how to destructively remove it without the freewheel remover (not recommended; primarily for freewheels don't have a remover available).

Comment: So in this case, the best option would be to find a tool that engages with the two holes in order to turn the ring anti-clockwise?

Comment: No, you don't remove the ring. The freewheel (whole unit) is threaded on in one piece to the hub. You take off the axle nut, put the FR-1 on to engage the splines, put back on the axle nut snug but not tight, turn the FR-1 one turn counterclockwise , remove the nut and turn the FR-1 by hand counter clockwise until the thing comes off.

Comment: If you use a pin spanner to open up the thing with the two holes, you'll end up making a mess with all the bearings and stuff falling out. You can find a Shimano freewheel tool (Park Tool FR-1) easily in most places. It looks like a cassette removal tool but is not the same. The destructive option is if you have no other choice -- I don't recommend it.

Comment: @ChristianLindig - If you look at the above picture very closely you will see that there are some splines on the inside of the cylindrical opening in the center of the sprocket assembly.  After you remove the nuts on the axle, a [cylindrical freewheel tool](http://media.nashbar.com/images/nashbar/products/product-hi/PT-FR12-NCL-TOP.jpg?resize=500px:500px&output-quality=85) will slide in and engage the splines. Loosely reinstall one of the nuts to hold the tool in place.  Then you need a large adjustable wrench to turn the tool.

Comment: Aren't both wheels removed by same spanner?

Comment: @TakahiroWaki - You get both of the wheels out of the frame with the same spanner. But, the question is to remove the freewheel (thing with all the gears on the back wheel), which you have to do with a special tool. See the first link in the answer on what Christian wants to do, and it'll be clear.

Comment: Gee, I was hoping the "destructive" method involved dynamite.